# I am trying to assignee a number to a month of the year, it should use if statements and no dicinaries

Tags: python

I am working on this challenge:

> Design the function month_name which takes a number between 1 and 12 and prints the corresponding name of the month. For example, given the number 2 your function should print February. When given an invalid number your function should not print anything at all. The function should use if statements and should not use dictionaries

So far I just have this:

```
# A month_name is a number -> string
# takes in a number and gives the coresponding month
def month_name(number1):
    1 = January
    2 = Febuary
    3 = March
    4 = April
    5 = May
    6 = June
    7 = July 
    8 = August
    9 = Suptember
    10 = October
    11 = November
    12 = December
```

Comment: So, what you have done is to type a list of months with the corresponding numbers. This is not valid Python: you cannot assign to a number literal. You don't use the argument of the function.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are not supposed to assign values to a number or a reserved keyword. this goes for any programming language

Python already has a well defined set of library. In this case I recommend using calendar

```
import calendar 

calendar.month_name(<month_number_here>)
```

In case you feel adventurous go with list or dictionary.

```
month_list = ['January', 'Febr......, 'December']
```

or

```
month_list = {1:January, 2:February, ...., 12:December}
```

In case of list index start at 0
So lookup `month_list[<month_number_here> - 1]`

In case of dictionary lookup `month_list(<month_number_here>)`